# Scottish Philosophy

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, humor

> The next three days
>   Things are going to be really boring.
>   The last YouTube and Facebook post will have been done.
>   There is nothing really to show for the activities up until now.
>   People die all too quickly.
>   They stress out for a little while and then are quiet.
>   A twit blethers on loudly and angrily,
>   But the details are ultimately inconsequential.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's

> Macbeth. The clue being in the title.

The next three days

> To-morrow, and to-morrow, and to-morrow

Things are going to be really boring.

> Creeps in this petty pace from day to day

The last YouTube and Facebook post will have been done.

> To the last syllable of recorded time

There is nothing really to show for the activities up until now.

> And all our yesterdays have lighted fools The way to dusty death.

People die all too quickly.

> Out, out, brief candle!

They stress out for a little while and then are quiet.

> Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player, That struts and frets his hour upon the stage, And then is heard no more.

A twit blethers on loudly and angrily,

> It is a tale told by an idiot, full of sound and fury

But the details are ultimately inconsequential.

> Signifying nothing.

Comment: I should add that this is the first puzzle on this site that I've ever been able to solve on my own, so thank you for posting it. It was fun to do.